# How can I use two "show" methods in the controller?

Tags: node.js

I need to search for a specific house as (/houses/:_id), and I also need to search for all houses (/houses). But the second "show" method is replacing the first. I'm still a beginner.

```
  const House = require("../models/House");

  class HouseController {
    async show(req, res) {
      const houses = await House.find({});
      return res.status(200).json(houses);
    }

    async show(req, res) {
      const { id_house } = req.params;
      const house = await House.findOne({ id_house });
      return res.status(200).json(house);
    }
  }

  module.exports = new HouseController();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you must use the index() method, to search for all houses and the show() method, to search for a specific house.

```
  async index(req, res) {
    const houses = await House.find({});
    return res.status(200).json(houses);
  }

  async show(req, res) {
    const { id_house } = req.params;
    const house = await House.findOne({ id_house });
    return res.status(200).json(house);
  }
```